# Decoding H264 streaming using android low level api

Tags: android, tcp, h.264

I am using MediaCodec low level Api in android to decode h264 raw stream received from IP CAMERA.
Raw stream from IP camera , receiving on TCP/IP connection.

To decode stream , My code is :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 MediaCodec mCodecc;
 MediaFormat mFormat;
 BufferInfo mInfo;
 ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers ;
 ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers ;

}
protected void Init_Codec()
{
  mCodecc = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
  mFormat =  MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);

  mInfo = new BufferInfo();
mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
  mCodecc.configure(mFormat, holder.getSurface(), null,0);
}

protected void Start_Codec()
{
  mCodecc.start();          
  inputBuffers = mCodecc.getInputBuffers();
  outputBuffers = mCodecc.getOutputBuffers();
}

private void OnRawStreamReceived(final ByteBuffer buffer)
{

 mHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run()
{
       int inIndex = mCodecc.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
   if(inIndex>=0)
     {
    inputBuffers[inIndex] = buffer;
    mCodecc.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0,buffer.limit(),System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
    }
       int outIndex = mCodecc.dequeueOutputBuffer(mInfo, 10000);
       switch (outIndex) {

    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
    outputBuffers = mCodecc.getOutputBuffers();
    break;

    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + mCodecc.getOutputFormat());
    break;

        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out! --- size : " + mInfo.size );
    break;

    default:
    ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];

            mCodecc.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
    break;
    }
}


int outIndex = mCodecc.dequeueOutputBuffer(mInfo, 10000);
```

But at this line of code , I'm always receiving "-1". and mInfo.size() is also I'm getting "0". and It is not displaying anything on given surface.

Which step I'm missing. please guide me. 
thanx

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you're passing in individual "access units", i.e. one frame of video per buffer.

What you seem to be missing is the codec setup block, which is expected to be in the first buffer submitted (could also be tucked into the `MediaFormat` via `format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ...)`).  Assuming that data is coming out of your particular encoder, all you have to do is queue the first buffer with the [BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) flag.

Comment: @Arun Have you got it?

Comment: @fadden. How to provide the required csd data using the flag, i mean where can i get the csd info for H264?

Comment: You will need to construct it if the source isn't providing it.  It's a blob of bytes containing the SPS/PPS data (see e.g. http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/the-h-264-sequence-parameter-set/).  If you encode data with the `MediaCodec` encoder it's always the first chunk; you can look at that to see exactly what the decoder is expecting.

Comment: Hi @Arun, I'm currently trying to do the same thing from and UDP stream that give me h264 raw stream. Did you get a solution to your problem?