# Can Android MediaCodec decode video h264 stream?

Tags: android, video-streaming, decode, h.264

I am going to use Android MediaCodec to decode h264 video stream,I want to know how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding H.264 from camera with Android MediaCodec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec)

Comment: @Mohsen Afshin  Now I have meet the same problem like this boy http://stackoverflow.com/q/15756735/2293921